# UIActionSheetDelegate Warning for View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4

I've set up a UIActionSheet popup with just two buttons and assigned an action to one of them.  The app compiles and runs and works properly but I get the warning:

```
warning: class 'MyViewController' does not implement the 'UIActionSheetDelegate' protocol
```

Here is my action sheet code:

```
- (IBAction)saveImage {


    UIActionSheet *saveMenu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save Image to Photo Library" 
                                                          delegate:self 
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Save Image", nil];

    [saveMenu showInView:self.view];
    [saveMenu release];
```

And the action I signed to the "Save Image" button:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (buttonIndex == 0) {

    UIImage* imageToSave = [imageView image]; // alternatively, imageView.image

    //Save it to the camera roll / saved photo album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);

}

}
```

Should I ignore this build warning?  Or how can I rectify the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `<UIActionSheetDelegate>` just before the curly bracket (`{`) on the line which starts with `@interface` in the header file. Eg:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> {
```

This will squash the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You error means you don't have implement the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol. To do that, you have to implement it in your interface like that :

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> {
}
```

The UIActionSheetDelegate protocol doesn't required methods, that's why your app don't crash.